# VirtualBox: Shortcut Error on Windows Guest On First Use Only

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, shortcuts

I'm running a Xubuntu 20.04 host and a Windows 10 guest. Inside the guest, I have a couple of folder shortcuts on my Windows desktop that map to folders on my host. Each time I start up my guest and try to click on one of my shortcuts, I receive the following error:

> The item " that this shortcut refers to has been changed or moved, so this shortcut will no longer work properly. Do you want to delete this shortcut?

For instance, here's the error window when I click on the shortcut to my host's Desktop:

[image]

Interestingly, this only happens the *first* time I click on the shortcut. The second time I click on it--and every time thereafter--it works properly until the next time I start up the guest.

The latest version of Guest Additions is installed, and both Xubuntu and Windows are fully up to date.

I would appreciate any insight the community can provide. Thanks!

Comment: What do these shortcuts look like?

Comment: It looks like the one in this image: [link](https://i.imgur.com/8P6CagU.png). It just maps to `E:\Desktop`, since I have `/home/<username>` mapped to the E: drive in the guest.

Comment: Is you problem the same as in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/252257/what-does-auto-mount-do-in-virtualbox-shared-folder-setup)?

Comment: I don't think so. That post is describing a Windows host with an Ubuntu guest. I have an Ubuntu host with a Windows guest.

Comment: I have the same issue with drive mapping shortcuts to the shared drive hanging off my linksys router (i.e. Samba server). First use of shortcut after logging into Windows always generates the error (even though the drive always maps). After that, no error until next logout/login. I'm used to it, but a fix would be nice.